# Cannot get Amplify to monitor MariaDB/mysql. amplify.agent.common.errors.AmplifySubprocessError

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

I am trying to get amplify to monitor mysql database on ubuntu server 20.04 running on a raspberry pi 4. I am sure I have set everything up correctly and have crossreferenced my work with many internet guides. However, mysql does not appear in the nginx amplify web interface after setting things up. My logs show the following errors:

```
2022-08-08 10:32:41,134 [1824839] supervisor ps nginx output: ['   2074       1 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf', '1740162    2074 nginx: worker process', '1740163    2074 nginx: worker process', '1740165    2074 nginx: worker process', '1740166    2074 nginx: worker process', '1740168    2074 nginx: cache manager process', '']
2022-08-08 10:32:41,161 [1824839] supervisor nginx objects: ['5057a79cf47c63d99f326ae55fea2c99bc0e2dcfd6bc5cdc5492d770f0a55284']
2022-08-08 10:32:41,162 [1824839] supervisor status objects: []
2022-08-08 10:32:41,162 [1824839] supervisor api objects: []
2022-08-08 10:32:41,228 [1824839] supervisor failed to find running mysqld via "ps xao pid,ppid,command | grep -E 'mysqld( |$)'" due to AmplifySubprocessError
2022-08-08 10:32:41,228 [1824839] supervisor additional info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/amplify/ext/mysql/managers.py", line 154, in _find_local
    ps, _ = (ps, None) if ps is not None else subp.call(PS_CMD)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/amplify/agent/common/util/subp.py", line 34, in call
    raise AmplifySubprocessError(message=command, payload=dict(returncode=process.returncode, error=raw_err))
amplify.agent.common.errors.AmplifySubprocessError: (message=ps xao pid,ppid,command | grep -E 'mysqld( |$)', payload={'returncode': 1, 'error': ''})
2022-08-08 10:32:41,229 [1824839] supervisor mysql objects: []
```

Does anyone understand these errors and could you help me fix this to get mariaDB showing up on Nginx Amplify?

Answer (score 1):

The mariadb daemon is called 'mariadbd' and amplify-agent is looking for 'mysqld'.

If you run

```
systemctl status mariadb
```

Then the line starting with 'loaded' should have the location of the service file

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
```

In this case it is '/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service'. Open the file in a text editor and find the line starting

```
ExecStart=
```

Then change the path from pointing to 'mariadbd' to 'mysqld'.
Then you need to reload the daemon and restart the services.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart mariadb
systemctl restart amplify-agent
```

The agent should now be able to find the process.

Comment: Thank you for this info. But could you please explain exactly what this is doing and why? I am a bit weary of making these changes to mariadb since I don't know what they do or how they will affect the rest of my mariadb. Thanks for any further elaboration.

Comment: ^^^ Could you possibly elaborate on this?

Comment: mysqld is a symlink to mariadbd if you run `readlink -f /usr/sbin/mysqld` you should see that it points to `mariadbd` and the systemctl commands are just for reloading the config

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This helped my understanding, and this is a working solution.

Comment: Would you be able to mark this answer as the accepted answer so that others can see that this question is answered?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this and get MariaDB showing up in Amplify, I did the following:

1. systemctl status mariadb

   ● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.10.3 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

This shows the location of the service file in `/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service`

2. `readlink -f /usr/sbin/mysqld` shows you that /usr/sbin/mysqld is a symlink pointing to `/usr/sbin/mariadbd`.
3. Open up the service file with a text editor at `/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service`
4. Find the line that starts with `ExecStart=`

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mariadbd $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION
```

and change the path from `/usr/sbin/mariadb` to `/usr/sbin/mysqld`

so it looks like:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION
```

Save the file and run:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart mariadb
sudo systemctl restart amplify-agent
```

Mariadb should now show up in Nginx Amplify.